# How to print elements of array of vectors of pairs?

Tags: c++, stl

I have an array of vector of pairs

```
vector <pair<int,int> > a[4]
```

.I have added elements to it using push_back.But I dont know how to print the elements.if i use an iteretor and print it like a[i].first or a[i].second it throws me error .Any other ways of doing it.Thanks in advance.

```
vector <pair<int,int> > a[4];
for(int i = 0;i < e;++i)
{
    int x,y;
    cin >> x >> y >> w;
    a[x].push_back({w, y});
    a[y].push_back({w, x});
}
```

This is how I push elements.But how to print them.

```
for(i=a[i].begin();i!=a[i].end();i++)
{
    cout<<a[i].second<<" ";
}
```

I am getting  the following error.I dnt know how to print them.

```
error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >*' and 'std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<int, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > >}')
  for(i=g[i].begin();i!=g[i].end();i++)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Why is this a topic i should not ask here??

Comment: Are you sure you want to have an array of `vector <pair<int,int> >`??

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Now i have edited my question.I guess its clear now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did **not** provide any code so that we could be able to know what's going wrong at your machine.
But here is a working example on how to access a vector of pairs:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

typedef std::pair<int, std::string> pairIntString;
int main()
{
   std::vector<pairIntString> pairVec;

   pairVec.push_back(std::make_pair(1, "One"));
   pairVec.push_back(std::make_pair(2, "Two"));
   pairVec.push_back(std::make_pair(3, "Three"));

   for (std::vector<pairIntString>::const_iterator iter = pairVec.begin();
        iter != pairVec.end();
        ++iter)
   {
      std::cout << "First: "    << iter->first
                << ", Second: " << iter->second <<std::endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Output, [see here](https://ideone.com/u31OO5):

```
First: 1, Second: One
First: 2, Second: Two
First: 3, Second: Three
```

**Edit #1:**

Now you provide code, but you are actually using an array of vectors of pairs: `vector <pair<int,int> > a[4];`. Further you put an `iterator` from the `begin()` method into the `[] operator`. It seems that you mixed a lot of things e.g. here `i=a[i].begin()` (one `i` is iterator and another is an index) and don't understand what they really are for. Please look at my example and read about arrays and vectors and how to access them properly. Also read about the difference of indexed and iterator based access.

**Edit #2:**

This loop:

```
for(i=a[i].begin();i!=a[i].end();i++)
{
    cout<<a[i].second<<" ";
}
```

should probably be:

```
/* loop through the fixed size array */
for(size_t idx = 0; idx < 4; ++i)
{
   cout << "Array element idx: " << idx << endl;
   /* get the iterator of the specific array element */
   for (vector <pair<int,int> >::const_iterator iter = a[idx].begin();
        iter != a[idx].end();
        ++iter)
   {
      cout << "First: "    << iter->first
           << ", Second: " << iter->second << endl;
   }
}
```

as you're having an array of vector of pairs you have two loop over the array and the vector. Because the array has a fixed size of `4` I used it as maximum.

Comment: I have made the changes in my post.How to print for that case

Comment: No i want it.i need to use it for adjacency list representation.can u tell me how to print elements

Comment: ya i am new to using stl in c++.Thats why these confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the code u have given.and i cant upvote it (i just have one reputation).

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick and correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
vector <pair<int,int>> vec[5];
vector <pair<int,int>> :: iterator it;

for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    for(it=vec[i].begin(); it!=vec[i].end();it++) cout << it->first << " " << it->second << " -> ";
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<pair<int,int>> v;
int n , in1 , in2;
cin >> n;

for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
{
    cin >> in1 >> in2;
    v.push_back(make_pair(in1,in2));
}

for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    cout << v[i].first << " " << v[i].second << endl;

return 0;
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 0):

I used this concept in a question and you can check out the code which do the same what you wanted

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

#define ll long long
#define ull unsigned long long
#define loop(i, k, n) for(int i = k; k < n ? i < n : i >= n; k < n ? i+=1 : i-=1)
#define pll pair<ll, ll>
#define pb push_back
#define po pop_back
#define mp make_pair
#define F first
#define S second
#define endl "\n"

int main()
{
    ll n, k;
    cin >> n >> k;
    ll arr[n];
    ll ansArr[n] = {0};
    vector <pair<ll, ll>> v[n];
    loop(i, 0, n) cin >> arr[i];
    loop(i, 0, n) {
        if(arr[i] < 0) {
            for(int j = i+1; j <= i+k && j < n; j++) {
                if(arr[j] > 0) v[j].pb(mp(arr[i], i)); // Taking input in pairs
            }
            for(int j = i-1; j >= i-k && j >= 0; j--) {
                if(arr[j] > 0) v[j].pb(mp(arr[i], i)); // Taking input in pairs
            }
        }
    }
    // Printing the result
    loop(i, 0, n) {
        for(auto it : v[i]) cout << it.F << " ";
        cout << endl;
        for(auto it : v[i]) cout << it.S << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```